# How i can access on JSON data in android?

Tags: android, json

In order to accede to my JSON data below :

```
[{"id":"1","code":"2020-04-05-20:12:12","cases":"313","recovered":"34","deaths":"6","datesituation":"2020-04-08","timesituation":"16:35:00"}]
```

I have use thi code below :

```
private void getGhanaSituation() {

        dataBaseHelper.deleteGhana();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest("MyURL",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject ghsituation = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                                int cases = ghsituation.getInt("cases");
                                int recovered = ghsituation.getInt("recovered");
                                int deaths = ghsituation.getInt("deaths");
                                String datesituation = ghsituation.getString("datesituation");
                                String timesituation = ghsituation.getString("timesituation");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
```

And now i used an API which give me an other format below :

```
{"ghana":{"existing":"273","confirmed":"313","recovered":"34","deaths":"6","date":"08th April, 2020","time":"16:35"},"global":{"existing":"1,066,963","confirmed":"1,468,891","recovered":"316,482","deaths":"85,446","date":"08th April, 2020","time":"16:35"}}
```

I changed my code :

```
private void getGhanaSituation() {

        dataBaseHelper.deleteGhana();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest("https://mazitekgh.com/covid19/v1/",
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject ghsituation = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                                int cases = ghsituation.getInt("confirmed");
                                int recovered = ghsituation.getInt("recovered");
                                int deaths = ghsituation.getInt("deaths");
                                String datesituation = ghsituation.getString("date");
                                String timesituation = ghsituation.getString("time");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
```

When a run the APP i receive an error :

```
*** Errororg.json.JSONException: Value : {"ghana":{"existing":"273","confirmed":"313","recovered":"34","deaths":"6","date":"08th April, 2020","time":"16:35"},"global":{"existing":"1,066,963","confirmed":"1,468,891","recovered":"316,482","deaths":"85,446","date":"08th April, 2020","time":"16:35"}} cannot be converted to JSONArray.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a parser for converting `JSON` to `Java Object` as it'll make your life easier and you'll be able to manipulate the data more freely.

You have a lot of choice,

- [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) is now in trend, you can use it quite easliy, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/61354fd0a20bf56072f6a1d0c82fb9fc) that shows how to use this library.
- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), here is also a quick [tutorial](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/)
- [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), another [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial) to help you get the hand of it.

They all got their pros and cons. Take a look at the githubs and pick one :)

Comment: Thanks. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), it can handle all headache about connection to Internet, convertation JSON to POJO (Java object class) and making asynchronous requests.

You can convert JSON to POJO class automatically with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

The data are of `String` type (e.g. "confirmed": "313") and not numbers like in ("confirmed": 313). That's the reason for the exception. Replace `.getInt()` with `.getString()`.